# Button Visible if score more than target

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

i have 3 button (level1, level2, level2buka) , I created a requirement if the score is more than twenty then visible button level2buka. The score save in database. I'm sure I am doing something wrong with the if and else statements but I tried playing around but couldn't find the solution.

```
 LevelUnsur rs = mScoreDataAdapter.getskor(1);

         if(rs.getSkor() > 20){
             level2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             level2buka.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }else{
             level2buka.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }
           skor.setText("Skor Level Unsur = " + rs.getSkor());
```

Comment: `if the score is more than twenty then visible button level2buka` then if condition should be `if(rs.getSkor() > 20)`

Comment: In question was "more than"... In the code "equal"...

Comment: what is happening in your case...?

Comment: the problem in LogCat java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tugasakhir/com.example.tugasakhir.menuleveldasar}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for equals to 20. you have to use `if(rs.getSkor() > 20)`